# Excel formula from textfile into cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I want to get formula from textfile into cell to identify the rows by named range.
I have this macro:

```
Dim objStream
Dim strData As String
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Charset = "utf-8"
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile ("path_of_txt_file")
strData = objStream.ReadText()
strData = Trim(Application.Clean(strData))
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.Value = "Name"
Range("A2").Select

Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = strData
```

The textfile contains like this:

```
=IF(
    OR(
        named range="this";
        named range="that";
        named range="something"
    );
    "True";
    "False"
)
...
```

Its a nested IF formula.

Without the equality sign it work, but i need to put it mannually.
With that, i get this error

```
Runtime error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

How can i fix this? I tried with Value instead of FormulaR1C1, but the same results.

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: What is your delimiter for formulas in excel? commas or semicolons?

Comment: Semicolons. Its work if i put the equality sign myself.

Comment: your code works fine, if i just replace the `;` with ',' in the txt file

Comment: Ohh, i change them and its work! You're right! Thanks!

Comment: but does your formula really work if you have a `,` instead of `;`

Comment: Write it to answer and i will accept it as solution :)

Comment: Also using `FormulaLocal` is possible (this way you use the string like you would enter it into the cell). Without `Local` the standart input needs to be used (`,` as separator and English formula naming)

Comment: yes, English formula naming was the 2nd problem for me, but i figured it out myself ^^ but yes, its important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesnt seem to be a problem with `Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = strData`. Replacing the `;` in the formula with `,` worked.

Posting the answer as it worked for OP.